# Kivy: How to access a nested screenmanager from within any screen in kvlang

Tags: python, kivy

When you want to change the root screenmanager in kvlang you can do the following from within any screen:

```
Button:
    text: 'press me to change the screen of the root manager'
    on_press: app.root.current = 'name_of_target_screen'
```

Or you can do the following if this button is located on the screen that is managed by the screen manager:

```
Button:
    text: 'press me to change the current screen'
    on_press: root.manager.current = 'name_of_target_screen'
```

However when you have a nested screen manager like this:

```
[Root screen manager]
     [screen 1]
     [screen 2]
       [BoxLayout]
          [sidescreen]
              [button to change nested screen manager]
          [nested screen manager]
              [nested screen 1]
              [nested screen 2]
```

I don't know how to change the nested screen manager from within the [sidescreen] because I don't know how to reference it.
Does anyone know?

A minimal working example:
http://pastebin.com/1i5Ysbu3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the nested screenmanager `id` within `<ScreenTwo>` to some value, like `id: nested_screenmanager`, and then pass it to the button, like `on_press: nested_screenmanager.current = 'SecondNested'`. The `ids` list is visible to all widgets within a rule.

Comment: Great, I knew it was something simple. I am totally confused by the name/id/classname chaos. My first mistake: not knowing which to use exactly. My second mistake: defining them in the `<NestedScreenManagement>` instead of `<Screen2>`. My third mistake, trying to set `root.nested_screenmanager.current` instead of just `nested_screenmanager.current` like you suggested. Thanks!